# Unable to call soap web service using ksoap2 library

Tags: android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I am new to android and very new to soap web service calling. I am trying to call soap based web service using ksoap2 library but continuously getting error message

> java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 405

But I am not able to understand why is it happening. I have searched over internet and could not found any solution to my problem.

these are the fields I am using:

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "Authenticate";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/Authenticate";
private static final String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
```

This is the wsdl url:
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL

This should be the request format:
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL

I have tested this service with web service studio and got the following request and working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><Authenticate xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <UserName>test</UserName>
  <Password>test</Password>
</Authenticate></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

I am trying to call this service using below code

```
request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);       
request.addProperty("UserName","test");
request.addProperty("Password","test");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

So please help me to get response from this service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `"http://demo.knowcross.com/TritonMobileService";` as `URL`? Service address you can find in wsdl and it is:

```
<soap:address location="http://demo.knowcross.com/TritonMobileService/Service1.svc"/>
```

so you should use it as `URL`.

EDIT:
You can set `ht.debug=true` and check whether `ht.requestDump` is correct. First of all you should add the namespace for properties like this:

```
PropertyInfo p = new PropertyInfo();
p.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
p.setValue("test");
p.setName("UserName");
request.addProperty(p);
p = new PropertyInfo();
p.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
p.setValue("test");
p.setName("Password");
request.addProperty(p);
```

Comment: I have replaced url with your suggestion but still getting same result:'java.io.IOException: HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500'

Comment: It's another error, probably your request isn't correct. See my edit, please.